# jQuery: load txt file and insert into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to load a *.txt file and insert the content into a div.
Here my code:

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#lesen").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url : "helloworld.txt",
            success : function (data) {
                $(".text").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

html:

```
<div class="button">
    <input type="button" id="lesen" value="Lesen!" />
</div>

<div class="text">
    Lorem Ipsum <br />
</div>
```

txt:

```
im done
```

If i click on the button firebug report following error:

```
Syntax-Error
im done
```

I don´t know what to do :-(

Comment: Use @Dogbert 's answer. Ignore the error message for now. It is just a sort of "ghost" error that will disappear if you try the code on an http server. It's the browser's way of complaining that what you're trying to do was meant for http://, not file:///.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You need to add a dataType - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#lesen").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url : "helloworld.txt",
            dataType: "text",
            success : function (data) {
                $(".text").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: @Khazl, what's the exact error message. Can you copy and paste here?

Comment: f(a=div.text, c="fxqueue", d=undefined, e=true)
f(a=div.text, c="fxqueue", d=function())
f()jquery....min.js (Zeile 16)
f(a=[div.text], c=function(), d=undefined)
f(a=function(), b=undefined)
f(a="fx", c=function())
f(a=3000, b="fx")
success(data="im done")
f(e=Object { url="helloworld.txt", isLocal=true, mehr...}, f=["im done", "success", Object { readyState=4, responseXML=document, mehr...}])
g(a=200, c="success", l=Object { xml=document, text="im done"}, m="")
g(a=readystatechange , e=undefined)
im done

Comment: i fix it :-) the problem was that i work local without apache... done!

Answer (score 37):

You could use jQuery.load(): http://api.jquery.com/load/

Like this:

```
$(".text").load("helloworld.txt");
```

Answer (score 5):

The `.load("file.txt")` is much easier. Which works but even if testing, you won't get results from a localdrive, you'll need an actual http server. The invisible error is an `XMLHttpRequest` error.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method to get the contents and insert into an element.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#lesen").click(function() {
                $(".text").load("helloworld.txt");
    }); 
});
```

You, can also add a call back to execute something once the load process is complete

e.g:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#lesen").click(function() {
        $(".text").load("helloworld.txt", function(){
            alert("Done Loading");
        });
   }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(".text").text(data);
```

Or to convert the data received to a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">     
   $("#textFileID").html("Loading...").load("URL TEXT");
 </script>  

 <div id="textFileID"></div>
```