# javascript / jquery - get data from server and display it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Let's say we have our javascript file in some directory on our computer, 
in the same directory we have folder called 'server',
in that  same 'server' folder we have 3 text files.

Simple enough. Now we want to display all of those 3 text files (in the 'server' folder) in our site, 
with jQuery.

Is it possible ? Can I get those files from server folder with jQuery and display them in my site like that ?

```
textfile1.txt
textfile2.txt
textfile3.txt
```

I think it can be done with AJAX, am I right ? 
If this possible, how can I do that ?

EDIT : I don't want to display the content of the files, I may even don't know the names of that files. 
I want to kind of loop in the 'server' folder and get all the files names displayed in my site.

Simple enough?

Comment: Use the load(0 method - http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: May want to check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470567/jquery-load-txt-file-and-insert-into-div

Comment: see my edit, I don't want to display the content, i want to display all files names that are in the server folder.

Answer (score 2):

You want ot use jQuery's [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Example. For this HTML:

```
<div id="content">
</div>
```

You'd have this script:

```
$('#content').load('remotepath/textfile1.txt');
```

Comment: I don't want to load any text files, I want to kind of loop in the server folder and get all the text files displayed in the site, But not the content of the text files, only the names..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery you can use the [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function.

If you are using straight javascript then you use AJAX and create an [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp)

Both methods are very simple to use. Just work through the documentation and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

> EDIT : I don't want to display the content of the files, I may even don't know the names of that files. 
>   I want to kind of loop in the 'server' folder and get all the files names displayed in my site. 
>   Simple enough?

No that's not possible with AJAX alone. You'd need a server script that returns you the list of files. E.g. you can use PHPs opendir()+readdir() or glob() functions to read all the files into an array, then do a exit(json_encode($files)); at the end.

That result you can then easily read after the AJAX request with e.g. jQuerys $.parseJSON() and loop through + display the files.