# Using jQuery and Ajax to get content from txt file and put on a div

Tags: jquery, ajax

Please, I trying to do this: the user type a word in the input text box and, after submit it, the program will look for the exact expression on a txt file an write the related description on a div. I would like to do this using jQuery and Ajax. What I have is:

```
<input type="text" id="textBox" />
<div id="description">The result must be written here.</div>
```

And my txt file has the following format (I don't know this format is good):

dog | A dog is a mammal.
snake | A snake is a reptile.
eagle | An eagle is a bird.

Comment: Use JSON format instead and just load the file if it is not huge

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: load txt file and insert into div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470567/jquery-load-txt-file-and-insert-into-div)

Comment: Please, read my question carefully. It's not the same as the other topic. I don't want to load txt and put the entire content on a div.

Comment: please show us what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

Even if you don't want to put the entire text block in the div, you're likely better off loading the entire text block into JSON, as @mplungjan noted.  That should give you better access to the data as you search through it for your preferred string.  Better still, if you can, include it directly into the page inside a hidden div.  Have each row of the div exist inside a span with `id="keyword"` where the keyword is whichever word they should type in.  Then use javascript to search for the element containing that id, grab the contents of the element, and write them into place.