# How to load a text file using JavaScript with a HTML combobox (<select>)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, combobox

First of all, thanks for reading the topic.

---

Now, I'm making a website using HTML5 and I need to load a text file according to the user choice in a combobox. I mean, the user selects an option from the combobox and the text from it should shown on a specific cell of a table. The number of times that the user wants without refreshing the site.

The problem is that the code is not working. The code:

The HTML for the combo box:

```
     <select id = "comboSelect">
        <option value="text1.txt">text1</option>
        <option value="text2.txt">text2</option>
        <option value="text3.txt">text3</option>
        <option value="text4.txt">text4</option>
        <option value="text5.txt">text5</option>
     </select>
```

The HTML for the table cell:

```
      <td colspan="5" class="text" id = "cuadroTexto"></td>
```

The JavaScript that does the rest of the work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
document.getElementById("comboSelect").addEventListener('change',function () {
    $(document.getElementById("cuadroTexto")).load(value);
    alert("Cargado");
},false);
});
```

---

*Edit 1:*

I think that the JavaScript is not recognizing the change event from the combobox.

I'm yet not working with a server.

Comment: similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470567/jquery-load-txt-file-and-insert-into-div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this is working

**CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#comboSelect").change(function () {
    $("#cuadroTexto").load(this.value);
    alert($(this).val())
});
});
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/krunalp1993/Qr6GK/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but is not working. And I checked that the script is properly getting loaded by the HTML.

Comment: Yes. By selecting it with the combobox.

Comment: I checked the page with Chrome and it says that there isn't an event listener.

And the script (Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined ) for this:     `alert($(this).val());`

Comment: Have you included jquery?

Comment: Yes. Like this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="js2.js"> </script><script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>` And I corrected.
And now the alert is working but the text is not shown.

Comment: Include jquery file before other js files

Comment: Yes, that was the thing I corrected. Still the text (inside the text file) is not shown.

Comment: I am still confused 

Are you trying to get content of .txt file to that td??

OR 

You want value of selected option in td??

Comment: The content of the text file.

Comment: So Are you sure is there any txt file that you are calling ?

Comment: Yes, they are at the same directory that *.html is. They are called text1.txt ; text2.txt ...

Comment: so you can see any ajax requests in console ??

Comment: Yes, the change of the select#comboSelect.

Comment: okay..
Add <td colspan="5" class="text" id = "cuadroTexto"><span id="ajX_load"></span></td>
$("#ajX_load").load(this.value);

Try this

Comment: $("#ajX_load").load(this.value);  instade of     $("#cuadroTexto").load(this.value);  ?

Comment: ? Do you have gmail??