# cant get the txt file to output to the screen jquery

Tags: jquery, html

i got every thing else to work. just having a problem with the .txt file. it just displays the doc path. does not display the actual document.

```
function callMeta() {

    var songName = $(nowPlaying).attr('data-songTitle');
    $('#songTitle').html(songName);
    var artistName = $(nowPlaying).attr('data-songArtist');
    $('#songArtist').html(artistName);
    var aBio = $(nowPlaying).attr('data-artistBio');
    $('.artistBio').html(aBio);
    var aCover = $(nowPlaying).attr('data-albumCover');
    $('img.albumCover').attr('src', aCover);
}
```

error, your browser doesn't support the HTML audio tag!

Comment: Where are you loading the .txt file? Some more relevant code?

Comment: Tell us about the problem and we might be able to help you.

Comment: <audio class="playsong" data-songTitle="Dance Floor" data-songArtist="Looz Chaynge: "
  data-albumCover="pics/LoozChaynge.jpg" data-artistBio="artistBio/loozChaynge.txt" src="music/danceFloor.mp3"> 
  error, your browser doesn't support the HTML audio tag!
 </audio>

Comment: nowPlaying is an array of audio tags

Comment: If you want to add more information, please **[edit]** your question.

Comment: when its displayed its just the text of the file path not the actual doc

Comment: You need jQuery **[`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)** here. And NOT `.html()`

Comment: okay, i tried that. it didnt work. basiclly its a audio player. it plays a sond and displays an album cover, artist name, and song name, as well as a bio. when the song ends the next one is loaded and it need to display the new data. i used data-"artistBio.txt" and data-"albumCover.jpg". i cant get the txt document to load and replace the test that was there before. i got the album cover to load and change just not the txt file

Answer (score 0):

Use **[`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)** to load the contents of a file. `.html()` modifies the inner html of the element with the argument passed.

```
var aBio = $(nowPlaying).attr('data-artistBio');
$('.artistBio').load(aBio);
```

You can also use **[ajax to load file contents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6470614/3639582)**.

Comment: so, i want to replace the html with a txt file... so, i load it then replace it? i did something simular with the image file that is right below it.

Comment: Image file just needs `src`, text file contents need `.load()`. To use `.html()` you need to use `ajax` to get the contents first.

Comment: okay, i figured it out.

var aBio = $(nowPlaying).attr('data-artistBio');
   $('.artistBio').load(aBio);
   $('.artistBio').html(aBio);