# ajax simple loading program

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am new to ajax and jquery. I am trying to load a simple .txt file into a div for testing purpose right now. But i keep getting an error(undefined). I the txt file and the html files are in the same directory. I even tried giving the full path but dint work. Below is my code snippet

```
<html>
<script type = "text/javascript" 
     src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script
<body>

<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "shop.css">

<div id = "header">
<p id = "welcome"> SHOPPINGCART.COM </p>
</div>

<div id = "container">
hi
<div class = "image">
<div class = "pic">
<img src ="images/item.jpg">
</div>
<div class = "label">
<p1> Item 1 </p1>
<p2> Price </p2>
<button type = "button" class = "add">
Add
</button> 
</div>
</div>
<div class = "image">
<div class = "pic">
<img src ="images/item.jpg">
</div>
<div class = "label">
<p1> Item 1 </p1>
<p2> Price </p2>
<button type = "button" class = "add">
Add
</button>
</div>
```

```
<script>
$("button").click(function(event) {
    $("#welcome").load("test.txt", function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr) {
        if (statusTxt == "success")
            alert("External content loaded successfully!");
        if (statusTxt == "error")
            alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseTxt);
    });
    //$(event.target).html("Added");

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What server solution are you building this on ?

Comment: i am not using any server as of now. I am using my browser to open the .html page.

Comment: "i  am not using any server as of now." That is your problem. Open the developer tools in your browser. Read the error messages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: load txt file and insert into div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470567/jquery-load-txt-file-and-insert-into-div)

Comment: TL;DR you need to add a `dataType: "text"` into a vanilla ajax post. `load()` expects html content, not txt.

Comment: The problem that the load() expects parameter to be of "https:". THank you guys