# Detect "Entry key" press for custom function

Tags: jquery, html, row, keypress

I want detect when user use <kbd>Entry</kbd>. I want this, because I want custom the action made by the key. The key will be add a new row on my table. Can you add me please?

Thanks.

**EDIT** :

This solution don't work. I try all answers and any solution work ... :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function stopEntryKey(evt) {
            var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null);
            var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : null);
                if ((evt.keyCode == 13) && (node.type == "text")) { 
                    return false;
                    $("tbody").html("<tr><td>Item1-col1</td><td>Item1-col2</td></tr>"); // Ajoute une ligne
                }
        }
        document.onkeypress = stopEnterKey;
    </script>
```

**EDIT 2 :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

This code work. Find here : [Prevent users from submitting a form by hitting Enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895171/prevent-users-from-submitting-form-by-hitting-enter)

**Now, I search to add a row when user press the Entry key. Who know how please?**

Comment: Use `$("tbody").append("html of row")`

Comment: @Mohammad : Look this : [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39450576/add-row-html-jquery

Comment: @Mohammad : I test this but he add a line but how to set my html file for one row? I have a HTML file for code one row, and I want when user use ENtry key to create a row with this HTML file.

Comment: [jQuery: load txt file and insert into div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470567/jquery-load-txt-file-and-insert-into-div)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add key event listener to detecting key press. You can use javascript [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) or jquery [`.keydown()`](https://api.jquery.com/keydown/) to adding [`keydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown) event listener. Then you should check if <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed, run your target code.

```
// Javascript
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(){
    if (event.keyCode == '13') {
        alert();
    }
});
// Javascript shortcut
document.onkeydown = function() {   
    if (event.keyCode == "13") {
        alert();
    }
} 
// JQuery
$(document).keydown(function() {   
    if (event.keyCode == '13') {
        alert();
    }
});
```

```js
window.onkeydown = function() {   
    if (event.keyCode == '13') {
      alert("Enter key pressed");
    }
}
```

Comment: That "Javascript shortcut" is awful and should not be used. It will break as soon as you have  more than one of them since it'll overwrite the previous one.

Comment: @ThiefMaster I provide three way to do work. This does not mean you should use all three ways together.

Comment: You provide three ways, and one of which is quite bad and is better not to be recommended to people who might not know the drawbacks.

Comment: @ThiefMaster I can't understand your mean. Why `onkeydown` is *quite bad*?

Comment: imagine you have foo.js using `document.onkeydown = ...;`   and bar.js also using it. now whatever is executed last will *replace* the other one

Comment: @ThiefMaster If what your said be right, It's not related to this question. Because question doen't use multiple js file or it does not mentioned in it. If you downvote my answer for the reason, it isn't right.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the HTML is as follow

```
<table>
     <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Col1</th>
          <th>Col2</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>

     <tbody>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Now the JS:

```
$(document).keydown(function() {   
   if (event.keyCode == '13') {
       $("tbody").html("<tr><td>Item1-col1</td><td>Item1-col2</td></tr>";  //this 'll add row in the table
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @KOUSIK. But didn't work. The  Entry  key send my form. So, how to change it please ?

Comment: Ok, so you have a form in that page and when you press enter the form is being submitted. Is it right? If it is then tell me when do you want to append a row in the table; when form 'll submitted or some other time?

Comment: I want custom the event for Entry key. By default, the Entry key send my form and I don't wan't. I just want add a row when user use the Entry key.

Comment: Ok, give it a try: <button type="button">Your Button</button>. Take a look on the type. Now check.

Comment: I don't understand why add a button ?

Comment: Do,you have a single input form?

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {   
  //something code
  //for something specific key:
  if (e.keyCode == 'someting_code_key') {
    // action
  }
}
```

[key code list](https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)

Comment: This is wrong, please test before you post - `function(e) <-- note the "e"`

Comment: i just forget about `e`, now is ok :)

Comment: don't assign `document.onwhatever`; it's likely to break if you have more than one of such assignments since it will replace previous ones. use `addEventListener` instead.