# How to add row to table when enter key press using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have my table here (not full because he take around 200 lines). This code is use for create and fill one row :

```html
<table>
  <TR>
    <TH>
      <FORM>
        <input name="designation" type="text" size="12" />
      </FORM>
    </TH> 
    <TH>
      <SELECT size="1" id="ERDF" >
        ...
      </SELECT>
    </TH>
    <TH>                
      <input name="famille" align="justify" type="text" size="12" />
    </TH> 
    <TH>
      <FORM>
        <input name="conditionnement" align="justify" type="text" size="12" />
      </FORM>
    </TH>
    <TH>
      <!-- Tableau dynamique -->
      <!-- APPELER LE CHAMP "total" -->
    </TH>
    <TH>
      <div>
        <input name="date_livraison" class="date_livraison" align="justify" type="date" size="12" />
      </div>
    </TH>
    <TH>
      <TABLE>
        <TH>Nom
          <input name="nom_recep" align="justify" type="name" size="12" />
        </TH>
        <TH>Portable
          <input name="port_recep" align="justify" type="text" size="12" maxlength="10" />
        </TH>
      </TABLE>
    </TH>
    <TH>
      <!-- Tableau fixe -->
      <TABLE>
        <TH>Meilleur prix
          <FORM>
            <input name="meilleur_prix" align="justify" type="text" size="12" />
          </FORM>
        </TH>
        <TH>Fournisseur
          <FORM>
            <input name="fournisseur" align="justify" type="text" size="12" />
          </FORM>
        </TH>
      </TABLE>
    </TH>
  </TR>
</table>
```

Then, I want add a row when user use the Entry key. For this, I use this (it's work) :

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(window).keydown(function(event){
                if(event.keyCode == 13) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                            $("body").load("C:\wamp\www\plat_web\new_line.php")
                }
                    // return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

So, I want add the HTML code (first) when user use Entry key. I tested it but I have several tags and several were not detected because they are on a new line. How to correct this please?

Comment: Your html code is confusing. Show html of row you what to insert.

Comment: This is the HTML for one row. I want this row. And this is HTML than I want use for create the row when user use Entry key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to inserting new row to table.

```
$("tbody").append("<tr>...</tr>");
```

But if html of row is long and you want to copy it from document, you can use [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) to copy html of row and use [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) to appending copied html to end of `table`.

```
$("tbody > tr:first").clone().appendTo("table");
```

```js
$(window).keydown(function(){
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $("tbody > tr:first").clone().appendTo("table");       
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col2</td>
        <td>Col3</td>
        <td>Col4</td>
        <td>Col5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How to specify a HTML file please?

Comment: @McNavy As mentioned in [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470567/jquery-load-txt-file-and-insert-into-div), you can use [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to get content of file on server. Like `$("tbody").load("/path/myHtml.html")` that get content of html file and insert it in `tbody`.

Comment: Don't work :(. I don't understand why . I edit my first post for update.

Comment: @McNavy `C:\wamp\www\plat_web\new_line.php` is path for server side language. But for client side you shouldn't use it. You should use for exampe `localhost/plat_web/new_line.php`

Comment: Don't work too. My file (new_line.php) is again on my wamp server. So, I can use `C:\wamp\www\plat_web\new_line.php`, right?

Comment: @McNavy No, javascript can't access to your dirive. Javascript only has access to files using domain and url.

Comment: And how to test my javascrcipt?