# How do I get jQuery's .load() to exclude div elements from the result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When using JQuery's `.load` to select a div from another page like

```
<div id="hello"> Hello </div>
```

How do i get it to exclude the div tags from the result?

So it just returns "Hello".

To be more specific what I'm actually doing is getting a div with some html in it from a web page and placing it in another.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.backup').on('click',function(e){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var file_name = "../ajax/"+{{ json_encode($data[0]) }} + " #" + id + ".text";
            console.log(file_name);
            //this is .load it takes in a string with a URL and a DOM element as a string.
            // it will take the dom element found at the URL and place it in .page_text
            $(".page_text").load(file_name);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What load, what divs, from where? There's no code?

Comment: Anyway, use `$.get` and just get the text like `$(data).find('#hello').text()`

Comment: use proper syntax

Comment: @Pekka웃 before editing it was. now it's correct syntax in question

Answer (score 1):

`$("#hello").text()` gives the content of div. Just use text method.

Comment: yes but the syntax for .load is something like `$('#element').load("url_to_look_in #id_you_want_to_get");` so i'm not really sure how use the .text method.

Comment: You changed the question dramatically. This question helps you. Load from file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470567/jquery-load-txt-file-and-insert-into-div

Answer (score 1):

There may be no real way to do this.

[`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) will load the resource and insert it into the DOM. The method has no parameter to exclude certain elements.

If you absolutely can't have certain elements entering your page's DOM, you would probably have to parse the resource you're loading on server side and remove the elements there.

If, however, you can live with the elements getting loaded, you just *don't want them to be visible*, you could do one of the following:

- Load everything and then [delete](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) all the elements you don't want
- Load everything and use CSS to hide all the elements you don't want. So for example, if you load everything into a `<div>` named `mystuff`, you can use CSS to hide divs:

  ```
  #mystuff div { display: none; }
  ```

Comment: Is there something like `.load` but where I can just set it to a variable the use .text on that element and push it into my textbox?

Comment: Not sure what you mean - you mean load a resource as text? That should be possible with what the others suggest (load it and then do a `.text()`)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#hello').text('Hello')
```

That should do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are looking for the content of the div.

Using only javascript

```
var getDiv = document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML //Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select a div

$("#hello")->this gives div with an id of hello

if you want to get the content of it

$("#hello").text() will return hello

Answer (score 0):

**Using Jquery as your mention:**

```
$('hello').text()
```

**or using Javascript:**

```
document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML
```

this will call only text inside the element with `hello` ID

Answer (score 0):

This will return text and the html content

```
$('#hello').html()
```

This will return the text content of the `div` alone

```
$('#hello').text()
```

Example

```js
$('.a').click(function(){

  alert($('.html').html());
});
  
$('.b').click(function(){

  alert($('.text').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class='a'> Get HTML </button>

<button class='b'> Get Text</button>
  
<div class='html'> 
<p> This is the HTML plus Content </p>
 </div>
<div class='text'>
  <p> This is the Text Content only </p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Why does everyone in this question think the OP wants the text content of the div? They just want to exclude certain elements, no?